# Как настроить работу Nginx с несколькими сайтами, где каждый сайт лежит в отдельном докер-контейнере

Tags: nginx, docker

На данный момент я имею тестовый стенд. У меня находятся два докер-образа сайта. Сайты статичный и имеют только index.html с названием сайта.
В другом контейнере я хочу иметь докер контейнер с обратным прокси и балансировкой нагрузи. Я хочу чтобы при вводе домена сайт, пользователь попадал сначала на контейнер с докером, а он уже посылал пользователей на нужный ему сайт в контейнере.

1. Как настроить Nginx, так чтобы он перенаправлял пользователя в контейнер с нужным ему сайтом.
2. Как будет выглядеть конфигурационный файл nginx.conf для того, чтобы он обрабатывал информацию для нужного сайта.

Первый сайт находится на localhost:6666
Второй сайт находится на localhost:5555
Nginx находится в образе с debian

Comment: Балансировка должна производится между первым и вторым сайтом?

Comment: на первом сайт будет работать только один контейнер. А второй сайт расположен в двух контейнерах и балансировка между ними

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для балансировки вам нужны 2 upstream:

```
upstream backend1 {
    server localhost:6666;
}

upstream backend2 {
    server localhost:5555;
}
```

Далее добавим конфиг прокси сервера, который будет слушать 80 и 443 порты:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;

    server_name first.site;

    location / {
        proxy_pass backend1;
    }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;

    server_name second.site;

    location / {
        proxy_pass backend2;
    }
}
```

И нужны конфиги серверов, для каждого из сайтов:

```
server {
    listen 6666;

    server_name first.site;
    root ...;
}

server {
    listen 5555;

    server_name second.site;

    root .... ;
}
```

Таким образом сайты будут открываться по доменным именам first.site и second.site. Запрос будет приходить на прокси-сервер, который будет балансировать на сервера, указанные в upstream.